# How do I round double value to 2 decimal places in C++?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have some calculations as below:

```
double a = 99.44, result;

result = 99.44 / 100 * 99.5;
```

The value stored in result will be 98.9428. How do I round the value into 98.94 and store into "result" ?

The setprecision method only can round the value during cout, but I want the value stored to be rounded for further calculations.

Comment: Do you want to *store* the rounded value (which might not be possible) or to *display* the rounded value?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude to store the rounded value

Comment: Then I suggest you *multiply* by `100`, cast to an integer type, and divide with `100.0`. It might *still* not be possible to store the exact value because of the way floating point values work on binary computers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is that the only way i can do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following algorithm:

- multiply with 100
- round to nearest integer
- divide by 100

This algorithm has problems with big values that are very close to maximum representable as the multiplication may overflow.

Another approach is to use the stream manipulators as you would with `std::cout` but stream into a string, and then convert that string back into a floating point number. This is much slower, but has no caveat mentioned above.

Comment: Refuted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java/12684082#12684082).

Comment: @EJP I think your test is faulty. Even `(0.03 % 0.01) != 0.0)` is true. You're ignoring the fact that not all numbers can be represented by floating point numbers. The point of rounding (and really, doing **any** calculation on) a floating point (whether to an integer, or to a decimal place) is to get the value that is the closest representable value to the accurate result; sometimes with some error. Now, perhaps this algorithm is wrong for that, but your test doesn't seem to prove it.

Comment: 'The fact that not all numbers can be represented by floating point numbers' *is the point of the test*. That's what it proves. If there was such a thing as a floating-point representation of 0.01 correct to exactly two decimal places, it would pass. It doesn't. QED.

Comment: @EJP I see. Then it refutes nothing about my suggested algorithm(s).

Comment: Yes it does. Your suggested algorithm relies on FP being able to represent numbers such as 0.01 exactly.

Comment: @EJP The algorithm relies on no such thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Floating-point variables don't have decimal places: they have binary places, which are incommensurable with decimal places.

If you want decimal places, you have to use a decimal radix, e.g. when formatting for output.